# How to add custom javascript or external js in AMP page?

Tags: javascript, validation, external, amp-html

I have tried adding external js file in AMP page but AMP validator rejects it. Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Might you mean [tag:amp-html]?

Answer (score 1):

AMP is a way to build fast rendering web page. In order to achieve this, AMP does not support external js. AMP have its own **AMP JS library** for more information [**CLICK HERE**](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/overview/)

Answer (score 1):

Actully now you have option to add custom javascript to a AMP page with `<amp-script>` component.
https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/custom-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround using the [amp-iframe](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe) component, but as mentioned in the previous answer, the whole idea of AMP is to build fast rendering pages without external JS, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Have a look at the [AMP components](https://ampbyexample.com/#components) currently supported by AMP and with one of them or with the combination of few of them, you will be able to replicate the features you are looking for.