# How add custom javascript for AMP project

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, amp-html

I am converting my existing project to AMP, which contains HTML, CSS, Bootstrap and Masonry grid. I need to apply masonry java script library for my AMP project.
I have tried in many ways and but Masonry grid is not working well.

```
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript"> 
   // init Masonry
    var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
    });
    // layout Masonry after each image loads
    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
      $grid.masonry();
    });  
</script>
```

I have used below method also.

```
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script amp-custom>
   // init Masonry
    var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
    });
    // layout Masonry after each image loads
    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
      $grid.masonry();
    });  
</script>
```

But both are not working...

Is there any alternative methods for achieving this ???

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to add javascript to an AMP page.
Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748634/add-javascript-in-amp-pages

Comment: @ Marlon Barcarol, I read it, but the thing is, there are tools , which generating our  existing projects to Amp. How they do that ? There should be at least one solution.

Comment: @VSM AMP does not support external javascript https://stackoverflow.com/a/48394533/5635098

This may be help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48570405/5635098

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running JavaScript in AMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237295/running-javascript-in-amp)